# SQLite3 Constructor create database Error - PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I want to implement a Language function into my Website. Im planning to do so with a simple SQLite Database System.

So far I got this Code:

```
private function openLanguagePack($package){
    if(!file_exists($this->getLanguagePackUrl($package))){
        $create = true;
    }
    $this->languagePacks[$package] = new SQLite3($this->getLanguagePackUrl($package));
    if($create){
        $this->languagePacks[$package]->queryExec('CREATE TABLE language (token nvarchar(50), text nvarchar(4000), PRIMARY KEY (token));');
    }
}
```

(The Code comes from an old Project and used an Older Version of SQLite.
Im rewriting it to SQLite3 now.

BUt with this code Im getting following Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to
>   open database: unable to open database file'

I cann't see the Error. In the [Documentation on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.construct.php) about the Constructor it says that ist automaticly creates a new database if there doesn't exist one. (At the moment the database doesn't  exist.)

Does somebody know about that issue?

Comment: I think you have answered your own question.....create a database.  Nowhere in the documentation link you posted does it mention that a database is _created_ for you automatically.  It is only creating an instance and opening the DB provided by the `$filename` parameter.  The exception to that is if you want to use an in-memory table,

Comment: Under Flags: `SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE: Create the database if it does not exist. `

Comment: Yes, but but according to your code you aren't using that flag.  I don't see how anything is getting automatically created for you.  _(For transparency, I'm not familiar with SQLite3, my comments are the observation of your code and the documentation link provided.)_

Comment: `By default, open uses SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE. `

Comment: Oppps...my brain stopped at end of that line and didn't travel to the next line to see `SQLITE3_OPEN_CREATE`.  My appologies....

Comment: No Problem - Im not familar with SQLite too so all I know is from the Documentation too ;) An Off Topic Question: Why do [http://docs.hhvm.com](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/sqlite3.construct.php) and PHP.net provide the same Contents?

Comment: If I were you I would debug the info going into the constructor.  Have you verified it is a valid file with sufficient permissions?  Perhaps a var dump of `$this->getLanguagePackUrl($package)` will provide some more insight.  The exception you are getting nudges me towards a problem with in the input.

Comment: Yes I checked the URI before it should be valid, but the database doesn't exist  | By the way I also Checked my phpinfo() and SQLite3 is enabeld

Comment: Does it fail when passed literal parameters?  For example, creating a test db in a same directory the script is running.  See if `$db = new SQLite3('mytest.db');` creates an instance.

Comment: I found the mistake | the URI was from the Root direktory but I was calling from the /admin Directory... the `../` was missing. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: I would scrutinize the input coming from `$this->getLanguagePackUrl($package)` in that case.  Something is wrong with this value.  Invalid permissions, file name, etc.

Comment: Go to hear! Happy coding!

Comment: The Problem always sits in front of the PC... :)